# Optimisation <xsl:apply-templates/> for a set of tags

Tags: xslt, tags, identity, apply-templates

How it is possible to **reduce** this record?

```
<xsl:template match="BR">
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="B">
    <strong><xsl:apply-templates /></strong>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="STRONG">
    <strong><xsl:apply-templates /></strong>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="I">
    <em><xsl:apply-templates /></em>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EM">
    <em><xsl:apply-templates /></em>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OL">
    <ol><xsl:apply-templates /></ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UL">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates /></ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LI">
    <li><xsl:apply-templates /></li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SUB">
    <sub><xsl:apply-templates /></sub>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SUP">
    <sup><xsl:apply-templates /></sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NOBR">
    <nobr><xsl:apply-templates /></nobr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a more dynamic solution. Also, read about the "identity rule" and overriding it. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Thanks for council. I necessarily esteem about "identity rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the elements to be created are not known in advance and only a few known elements needs to be processed in another, more specific way, here's a more dynamic solution**:

```
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $vUpper, $vLower)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

where `$vUpper` and `$vLower` are defined as:

```
<xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
 "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 "/>

<xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
 "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
 "/>
```

**There must be templates matching the few known elements that should not be processed in the above way.** These more specific templates will override the more general template above. For example:

```
 <xsl:template match="specificName">
   <!-- Specific processing here -->
 </xsl:template>
```

**Also, the generic template above, matching elements should be overriding the ["identity rule"](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** (template).

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Well, I will know. The only thing that to me is not clear in your concrete code is what for there variables are used. The set of letters remains to constants.

Comment: @kalininew: The two xsl:variables must be globally defined -- then they can be used anywhere in the code (more than once). This will save a lot of keystrokes and makes the code a lot more readable.

Comment: How about using `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` instead, so that attributes will not be stripped? If the source is HTML, as it would appear to be, there may be attributes worth keeping on `ul`, `ol`, and `li` elements, in particular.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I have added your new line `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` in a code. On an exit I have received: if to set at an element a class at transformation it passes not in attribute of an element, but in text knot. For example `<STRONG CLASS="aaa">lorem ipsum</STRONG>` passes in `<strong>aaa lorem ipsum</strong>`. How it can be corrected?

Comment: @kalininew, you need to have the "identity rule" template, preferrably as the first one in your stylesheet.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I have read about "identity rule". I used it in our project. It has very much reduced a code. Thanks big.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
<xsl:template match="LI|SUB|...">
   <xsl:element name="{translate(name(),
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't think, there's a tolower function in XSLT (at least not in 1.0)

Comment: @chris_l: Just to confirm - no, there isn't.